# Errors trying to overload template class friend << operator

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, friend-function, template-classes

Trying to code a better version of array type i have run into an issue. For some reason the declaration doesnt work. It throws at me bunch of weird errors. Tried looking up the issue but havent found anything so far. Here is the code:

```
Template <class T>
class SafeArray {

private:
    int size;
    int elements;
    int index;
    T* arr;

public:

    SafeArray(int n);
    ~SafeArray();
    void push_back(T item);
    void resize(int size);
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const SafeArray<T>& ar)


};
```

And the implementation outside the class:

```
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator << <T> (std::ostream& os, const SafeArray<T> & arr) {

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.elements; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want [friend template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friends), the `friend` declaration should be

```
template <class T>
class SafeArray {
    ...
    template<class X>
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const SafeArray<X>& ar);
};
```

the implementation should be

```
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const SafeArray<T> & arr) {
    ...
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wdkkFH0R2Cb2q60c)

BTW: In the implementation of `operator<<`, I think `std::cout << arr[i] << " ";` should be `std::cout << arr.arr[i] << " ";`.

Comment: I have done so but i still get errors:
error C3646: 'T': unknown override specifier  
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'SafeArray<T>' being compiled  
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition  
error C2059: syntax error: '&'  
error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body

Comment: @TomatoLV There're some other issues, see the live demo I posted.